# how java thead pool executor deals with interrupted thread

Tags: java, threadpool

I create a `ThreadPool` with 10 fixed threads in it. At times I need to interrupt a longrunning thread in the thread pool, mostly because they are blocking in some operation and a timeout happens and I interrupt the thread. I catch the `InterruptedException` and set the Thread's status to interrupt as well. In that case, my question is, does `ThreadPool` create a new Thread and replace the interrupted thread with a new One ?
Below is the example code which gets executed by the Thread. Question is, when this thread get interrupted, does thread pool replace this thread with a new one ?

```
 public ResponseMessage call(){
    Future<ResponseMessage> future = CacheManager.getInstance().asyncFetch();
    ResponseMessage response = null;
    try {
        response = future.get();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
        //create a blank response
    }

    return response;
}
```

Comment: what kind of threadpool are you using?

Comment: You know that `get()` has an overload that accepts a time-out, right?

Comment: Please ignore the stopwatch, and yes, I know about get with time-out method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not interrupt threads that you do not "own," because you don't know how they respond. Since you don't have control over the thread scheduling, you really don't know that a given thread is executing a particular task at the instant you interrupt it

If you want to cancel a task you've given an executor service, call `cancel(true)` on its associated `Future`. When your task detects an interrupt request, it should preserve the interrupted status by calling `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`.

If you do this, the executor will handle the interruption cleanly because it interrupted the thread itself, and knows that the thread was executing a task when the interrupt occurred.

Comment: I am following exactly as you mentioned, I cancel the future and in the callee thread, I preserve the status of the interruption.

Comment: There is a caller of the above code, which submits this callable task to the thread pool and cancels the task using future.cancel(true)

Comment: You should be alright then. The code looks strange with a `Future` being used from within another task though, so I suspect things could be simplified significantly.

Answer (score 0):

From the step by step debugging, I suppose the interrupted thread will continue to getTask from the worker queue.
The interrupted status already cleaned up before getTask.

For example, if you are using FixedThreadPool with LinkedBlockingQueue, the interrupted status is cleaned inside of `queue.take()` by  `ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly()`

```
public final void acquireInterruptibly(int arg) throws InterruptedException {
    if (**Thread.interrupted()**)
        throw new InterruptedException();
    if (!tryAcquire(arg))
         doAcquireInterruptibly(arg);
}
```